# rails - how to override default views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

by default, when i ask rails controller to do messages/index, he does

```
def index
 respond_to{|fmt| fmt.html}
end
```

and shows app/views/messages/index.html.erb

there is a customer which wants his instance of the platform to display **views** differently (and changes cannot be done with css only).

solution i think of would be

1. create directory app/views/#{customername}, which would have same structure as app/views, but would only have views which have to override default ones.
2. setting an array constant containing list of views which have to be overriden (if not, they should load the default views)

   ```
   CUSTOM_VIEWS["messages"]=["index","show","edit"]
   ```

   somewhere in the customer-specific config file
3. in all controller actions do something like

   ```
   def index
    respond_to do |fmt| 
     fmt.html do
      if CUSTOM_VIEWS[params[:controller]].include?(params[:action])
       #override default app/views/messages/index.html.erb with app/views/customername/messages/index.html.erb 
       render "#{customername}/#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}"
      end
     end
    end
   end
   ```

or is there better/faster solution/plugin to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe "view_paths" along with "prepend_view_path" can be an answer to my question

for example

http://www.axehomeyg.com/2009/06/10/view-path-manipulation-for-rails-with-aop/

upd:

solved with simple add to application_controller

```
def override_views
 if APP_CONFIG['pr_name']!=nil
      ActionController::Base.view_paths=[RAILS_ROOT+"/app/custom_views/"+APP_CONFIG['pr_name'],RAILS_ROOT+"/app/views/"]
 end 
end
```

where APP_CONFIG['pr_name'] is specific product name.

basically what it does is loading custom view from app/custom_views/customername/ if it exists for specific controller action, if not it loads default view from app/views/

Comment: This will unfortunately persist across requests.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/125-dynamic-layouts